# What is the syntax for named yield with both names and parameters in ruby/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yield

One could use `yield` with a `:name` in views in rails:

```
= yield :some_place
```

so then using then using `content_for :some_place do ...` to insert a code block only in there where `yield :some_place` is placed (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method).

Also ruby allows passing parameters in the yiled (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_blocks.htm):

```
def test
   yield 5
   puts "You are in the method test"
   yield 100
end
test {|i| puts "You are in the block #{i}"}
```

But I didn't find anything about using **yield/content_for both with names and parameters** in rails views:

```
= yield :some_place, 5, 6

...

= content_for :some_place do |a,b|  
  h3 = "Yield provided parameters: #{a} and #{b}"
```

Is it possible? Where is the official rails or ruby syntax for yield statements and passing blocks?
I heard something about the Proc.new() that could be somehow related to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

content_for(:name) evaluates first, and stores a snip of HTML for later use. yield(:name) only fetches this content. Hence, you can't pass arguments into a method that was already called, and won't be called again.

You probably merely need to cut a partial HTML.erb file, and render it from your target location. Render takes named parameters as a hash.